# How to replace £ in XML

Tags: xml, xmlparsing, xmlnode

When I pass a String to XML I have **£** Symbol.Suppose if the string is 'test£' then it gives the exception as invalid String as we have £ in String. Is that possible to replace this **£** symbol. I tried `&pound; and &#163;`but both not working.

Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean not working?

Comment: @Adrian If I have String as 'test£' then it gives invalid String exception. Is that possible to replace £ symbol in the String. I updated the description of my question

Comment: Have you tried escaping it by using a \ ? Normally a `$` would require escaping like so: `\$`. Perhaps is the same for a pound symbol.

Comment: @crmprogdev \£ also not working it shows the exception as String not valid.

Comment: Could you demonstrate with code?

Comment: Is that during creation of xml you are facing error? or xml contains that character and during parsing you are facing? which one?

Comment: @Santanu It's during parsing

Comment: Based on my experiments, I would propose that *your XML is not valid*. Please upload your XML [here](https://validator.w3.org/) and verify that no errors are present.

Comment: Sorry for my Inconvenience that  \£ is working the thing is I didn't update the changes in all places. Apologize me and thank you all for your support.